# SSH and SCP two hops with different keys between hops

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunnel

In the below:

- `HostA` is workstation.
- `HostB` is a jumpbox.
- `HostC` is the target system.

I need to SSH and at times SCP files from `HostA` to `HostC` and I can only connect to `HostC` via `HostB`. Complicating matters is that the username and keypair for `HostA -> HostB` is different from `HostB -> HostC` and I do not have access to the keys on `HostB`. What is the proper way to set this up?

Answer (score -1):

You want to use `ProxyJump` in `~/.ssh/config`. Create the file if it doesn't exist. It should look something like this:

```
Host HostB                                                                          
  User bob
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.bob                                                 
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  DynamicForward 1028

Host HostC                                                                        
  User alice                    
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_alice                                                  
  HostName 5.6.7.8                                                          
  ProxyJump HostB
```

Now a `ssh HostC` or `scp HostC` will go through the jumpbox with the usernames and keys configured.

Comment: That seems to try and use a `~/.ssh/id_alice` that exists on `HostA` (my machine). I need to use a key that's only on `HostB`.